# Getting goto was unexpected at the time

Tags: batch-file

I am currently making a game that has a persuasion system in it.  I had all the code for one of the systems set up, but then I set up 2 more, and it started give me an error that said '(number) was not expected at this time'. when I put in 2 for the second choice, and 3 for the 3rd choice.

The code is like this.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (

set "DEL=%%a"

)
set name=Quantum

cls 

color 0a

Echo King Redwood: So 2000?

pause >nul

echo.

call :colorText 09 "1. 2500"

echo.

call :colorText 0e "2. 3000"
echo.
call :colorText 0c "3. 4000"
echo.
echo 4. 2000
echo.
set /p "purs=Enter:"
if /i %purs% == 1 ( 
goto CheckB )
if /i %purs% == 2 ( 
goto CheckY )
if /i %purs% == 3 (
goto CheckR )
if /i %purs% == 4 ( 
goto Convo )


:CheckB
set bleu=%random:~-2,1%
if %bleu% GTR 10 (
goto CheckB )
if %bleu% LSS 0 (
goto CheckB )
set /a  num = 3
set /a  reward = 2500
goto Res
:CheckY
set Yel=%random:~-2,1%
if %Yel% GTR 10 (
goto CheckY )
if %Yel% LSS 0 (
goto CheckY )
set /a num = 5
set reward = 3000
goto Res

:CheckR
set red=%random:~-2,1%
if %red% GTR 10 (
goto CheckB )
if %red% LSS 0 (
goto CheckB )
set /a num = 7
set /a reward = 4000
goto Res

:Convo
set /a reward = 2000
Echo %name%: I think that is a reasonable price.
Echo King Redwood: Very well.
Echo King Redwood: We will now take you to make sure you are
echo ready.
pause >nul


:Res
if %bleu% GEQ %num% goto Succeed
if NOT %bleu% GEQ %num% goto Fail

:Succeed
Echo %name%: I think that the struggles for such a long trip will be more then that
Echo %name%: How about %reward%? 
Echo King Redwod: OK %reward% will work.
pause >nul 
goto end

:Fail
Echo %name%: I think that you can give me %reward%.
Echo %name%: You know, for the struggles that there will be along the way.
echo If 2000 isn't good enough for you, I'll just have someone else do it.
pause >nul

:end
exit


:colorText
echo off
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > "%~2"
findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul
del "%~2" > nul 2>&1i
```

Comment: I made an edit,I changed the set num and set reward under :CheckR and Y to set /a instead, now. but that still gives me an error.

Comment: Comment out `@echo off` to see what actually happens; do not double-click the batch-file, but run it by opening a command prompt window and typing its path...

Comment: For instance, `%bleu%` is an empty string under `:res` because `bleu` is not set going through either `:CheckY` or `:CheckR` or `:Convo` (this list may be incomplete). Hence, `if %bleu% GEQ %num% goto Succeed` results to something like `if  GEQ 3 goto Succeed`… Apparently wrong syntax…

Comment: I tried changing the     %bleu% and all the other variables to something like color so that it was the same and in everything, but I still get the same problem.  Except now I get  it saying that 0 was unexpected at this time.  @JosefZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure to close the FOR loop by putting a ) before :CheckB.

For the 'was not expected at this time' error, you're sometimes comparing an empty variable to something. For example, by following CheckY, you set Yel, then proceed to Res and check Bleu, which is empty because it hasn't been set. You're putting nothing next to the binary GEQ operator, and that's why it's complaining.

Tip: to debug, try inserting ECHO statements like this:

```
:Res
echo bleu=%bleu%,num=%num%
```

Another problem: when using SET, do not surround the = by spaces. `SET /a` will work with spaces around =, just because of the nature of /a, but plain SET will not. Well, it will append your variable name with a space and prepend your value with a space, which is not what you want.

Another tip: you can constrain what RANDOM returns through SET /a and the modulus operator, like this.

```
SET /a red=%random% %% 11
```

This will set red to a number between 0 and 10, so there is no need for the substrings and goto routines you're using after picking your random number.

Also, consider using `EXIT /b` to exit the batch file and not the whole CMD environment.

Comment: First, the  the `FOR` loop body is already closed by  `)`  parenthesis just before `set name=Quantum`…

Comment: Thank you.  This has helped me a lot. @soja.